# Why is it so difficult to get phpize to work...?

Tags: centos, imagick, pecl, phpize

Believe me, I'm not somebody that easily gives up but I am about to on this one...Also I'm not a linux expert but normally I can get arround just fine.

I started installing Imagick and all went fine except for the 'pecl install imagick'. It gives me the error **'phpize' failed**, a common error as became clear after googling it, and after searches on this forum.

Everything that is mentioned doesn't work, installed AND enabled the EPEL and Remi repository's. **The Remi's for all php version's 55,56,70,71 are enabled and listed.**

I'm supposed to get the **php-devel** package installed to get phpize working but it just isn't there, yum searches don't find anything and updating everything does nothing either.

**The target PHP version is 7.0 on CentOS 7** 
People say it is a bug in the PEAR extension and tried the 'patches' but nothing...I'm rebooting after each major change to be sure things are loading, if that is even necessary. I have full root access so that can't be it.

If it IS a bug, why is it still there. The only thing I need is the imagick library installed. Nowadays humans can make computers think, but getting phpize to work is hard apparently...

Sorry for ranting, but I hate it to spend time on things that should be easy to fix.

I hope somebody can help me, if more info is needed, please let me know ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **remi** repository, you usually don't need the `pecl` command, as most of extensions are available there, see the [list](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status).

As explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/):

```
yum install php-pecl-imagick
```

or, for SCL version

```
yum install php70-php-pecl-imagick
```

This is the latest version , build against the latest version of ImageMagick 6 (not 7 which lack lot of features).

The `php-devel` and `php-pear` package are also available, and allow to use the `pecl` command.

> The Remi's for all php version's 55,56,70,71 are enabled and listed.

When using multiple versions (SCL) it also works, example for 7.0, only have to enable the SCL:

```
yum install php70-php-devel php70-php-pear
scl enable php70 bash
pecl install imagick
```

Comment: Starting a shell with `scl enable php<version> bash` worked for me